# 'object' does not refer to a package or module

Tags: mojolang

I tried the below in Jupiter, and it is working fine,

[image]

But one I tried to use at at `file.mojo` as:

```py
from python import Python

# The Python way: `import requests as http`
let http = Python.import_module("requests")

# Now use numpy as if writing in Python

fn main():
    let url = 'http://google.com'
    let response = http.get(url)
    let content = response.text
    print(content)
```

I got the errors:

```
/home/hajsf/mojo/python.mojo:1:20: error: recursive reference to declaration
from python import Python
                   ^
/home/hajsf/mojo/python.mojo:1:6: note: previously used here
from python import Python
     ^
/home/hajsf/mojo/python.mojo:1:1: error: 'object' does not refer to a package or module
from python import Python
^
mojo: error: failed to parse the provided Mojo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recursive reference to declaration` comes from your file being called `python.mojo`, if you rename it and fix this you will get `cannot call function that may raise in a context that cannot raise`, to fix this one the import of the module has to be inside a function that can catch exceptions, like:

```
from python import Python

fn main() raises:
    let http = Python.import_module("requests")

    let url = "http://google.com"
    let response = http.get(url)
    let content = response.text
    print(content)
```

the `raises` after `main()` is the important part, point 4 from [here](https://docs.modular.com/mojo/programming-manual.html#fn-definitions).